# Adding a max-retry feature to Java EE authentication

Tags: jakarta-ee, authentication

For my app I use a datasource realm for authentication.

I would like to know if there is an easy way to add some features to j_security_check, like max retries or an idle time between 2 login attempts?

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible by writing a JAAS module. It involves quite some work though if you haven't done it before.

Comment: Thanks for your reply

So there is no simple way to add features to auth.
I think I will rewrite a authentification module using esapi